# Show a set of car models after the user chooses the car brand in Django forms

Tags: django, forms, django-models

I am using Django 3.2 to make an uber clone and that when I want to allow the users to register with their vehicle I first want the user to be able to choose the car brand, and then afterwards choose the car model which is sorted according to the car brand.

```
class Vehicle (models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    vehicle_colour = models.CharField(choices=COLOURS, max_length=10)
    vehicle_number = models.CharField(max_length=8)
```

I want to add some choices for the `brand` and `model` field, but I feel like I might need some javascript to intervene. Do you know any method that I could use to get this done?

Your help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Two forms and views.

The first view presents the user with a list of brands to choose from. The view ends with something like

```
# brand is the brand which the user selected in this view
return HttpResponseRedirect( reverse( 'cars:register_vehicle', 
     kwargs={ 'brand': brand } )
```

The second view's URL pattern will parse the brand from above out of the URL (which will be something like "cars/register_vehicle/tesla"), and the urlconf for it (in app "cars") will be something like

```
url(r'^register_vehicle/(?P<brand>[\w]+)/$', RegisterVehicle.as_view(), name='register_vehicle')
```

Comment: Ok so then using the GET method I only see whats the car brand and then throw out the possible list, Am I right? And what do you think would be the best format to store all the data? In a .json file?

Comment: Django is normally wrapped around a database. I'd expect there to be  a brands table, and a car-models table. The first view would display the names of most if not all of the brands in the table. The second would be filtered to display all the models with the chosen brand. But the details all depend on what you are building.

Comment: If you are determined to build a one-view "app" using some Javascript framework on the front end, the usual Django product on the server end is called the Django REST framework. But this is a huge way down the "might need some JavaScript" rabbit-hole!

Comment: Ahhh right, I get what you are trying to say, and I feel the method of 2 tables to store brands and models is a good way to move forward. Thanks a lot @nigel222

Comment: Hey @nigel222 , how do I send the brand of the car from my views.py to my forms.py? I get the brand to the 2nd view but I'm a bit confused on how to make a query in my forms.py as a choice list before rendering to the user

Comment: Second view would take the brand and use a queryset on the car-models table to obtain all the models of that brand. You might use a ModelChoiceField in the form.

Comment: yeahh but how do i do that in terms of coding? How do I send a value in from my `views.py` to my `forms.py`. Please help me out @nigel222